# Shopify - how to change color of nav items on homepage only?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How can I change the color of the nav items on the homepage only using the Retina theme in Shopify? I tried to use in my code:

```
{% if template == 'index' %}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: you mean when you hover nav item?

Answer (score 3):

Please check [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/change-color-of-one-link-in-navigation-menu-301666).

if you still have problem, please give me your domain link.

Comment: Hi Minh, this is useful, but doesn't exactly answer my question. I need the top-level nav items ONLY on the homepage to be a different color (white), while the nav items on other pages stay black. I've been able to turn one top-level nav item on the homepage white (has no submenu), but still having difficulty changing all the items.

Comment: can you share with me the link of your website?

Comment: Thanks it was a client site and another dev already solved the issue.

Comment: yeah, glad to hear about that :)